# maven in vscode not working but works through terminal

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, path

When running mvn commands through the vscode I get errors, but when I use the same commands in the vscode terminal window they work. I think this is a path issue that vscode is using to click on the commands.

$ mvn clean -f
(working)

$ mvn clean -f "/home/NAME/Desktop/School/Project/pom.xml" /usr/share/maven/bin
(vscode runs this and it doesn't work)

This problem prevents me from creating maven projects using vscode.

Comment: you say the same commands but the example you show is not the same commands. so is it the same commands or not?